# Changing datatype from int to time causing error in existing value

Tags: mysql, sql, time

I got a new project in which hours information was stored as data type int

Now, I need both information (hours and minutes)

after some research i found that datatype time will be good to store hours and minutes information in a column.

As we change the existing data type from int ( let's say having value 8 ) to type time the existing value changed to 00:00:08

**Problem** After changing the datatype hours shifted to seconds in datatype time

Can someone guide me how to properly mapped it from int to time?

Table Structure

```
before
    Name    Type
    hours   int

after
    Name    Type
    hours   time
```

actual result

```
00:00:08
```

expected result

```
08:00:00
```

Comment: don't  you need second value

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary column as `TIME` data type and use this query:

```
UPDATE t
SET hours_temp = SEC_TO_TIME(hours * 60 * 60)
```

When you're satisfied with results, drop original column and rename the temp column.

---

If you have already messed up the data then use this instead:

```
UPDATE t
SET hours_temp = SEC_TO_TIME(EXTRACT(second FROM hours) * 60 * 60)
```

Comment: Assuming the column datatype has already been changed, I think `UPDATE t SET hours = SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(hours) * 60 * 60)` might also be useful.